# What happens at JVM or memory level when we say object is collected by Garbage Collector or GC?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

When we say object is collected by GC. What does it really do in the background? Does it deletes all the data occupied by particular object? or just marks the memory area used by the object as "reusable" so whenever new objects are created they will be overwritten on this memory area?

Comment: It just marks the memory area as reusable.  Nothing else.

Comment: @DavidWallace thanks. But the link in one of the answers to question http://javabook.compuware.com/content/memory/how-garbage-collection-works.aspx explained "there is no explicit deletion and no memory is given back to the operating system."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

memoris are mapped like a tree with the garbage collector. After the garbage collection the link of memories (i.e node of tree) are removed from the tree. So if there is a node with no connection with gc roots that means those memories are free. Those can be used by other usages.

It is actually tough to describe in single sentence, and instead of reinventing the wheel I will suggest you to read the following links to know about how gc works

http://javabook.compuware.com/content/memory/how-garbage-collection-works.aspx.http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/garbage_collect.html

Comment: The compuware.com link in this explained what I was looking for "When an object is no longer used, the garbage collector reclaims the underlying memory and reuses it for future object allocation. This means there is no explicit deletion and no memory is given back to the operating system."

Answer (score 1):

Heap memory will be checked to identify objects which are in use and which are not. 
**Unused objects will be deleted.**

The memory used by an unreferenced object will be reclaimed.

Comment: The question is just, IMHO, what "deleted" means in that context?

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't answer the question at all.

Answer (score 1):

Garbage collection is the process of looking at heap memory, identifying which objects are in use and which are not, and deleting the unused objects. An in use object, or a referenced object, means that some part of your program still maintains a pointer to that object. An unused object, or unreferenced object, is no longer referenced by any part of your program. So the memory used by an unreferenced object can be reclaimed.

The information learned from the object allocation behavior can be used to enhance the performance of the JVM. Therefore, the heap is broken up into smaller parts or generations. The heap parts are: **`Young Generation, Old or Tenured Generation,`** and **`Permanent Generation`**

[image]

The **Young Generation** is where all new objects are allocated and aged. When the young generation fills up, this causes a minor garbage collection. Minor collections can be optimized assuming a high object mortality rate. A young generation full of dead objects is collected very quickly. Some surviving objects are aged and eventually move to the old generation.

Stop the World Event - All minor garbage collections are "Stop the World" events. This means that all application threads are stopped until the operation completes. Minor garbage collections are always Stop the World events.

The **Old Generation** is used to store long surviving objects. Typically, a threshold is set for young generation object and when that age is met, the object gets moved to the old generation. Eventually the old generation needs to be collected. This event is called a major garbage collection.

Major garbage collection are also Stop the World events. Often a major collection is much slower because it involves all live objects. So for Responsive applications, major garbage collections should be minimized. Also note, that the length of the Stop the World event for a major garbage collection is affected by the kind of garbage collector that is used for the old generation space.

The **Permanent generation** contains metadata required by the JVM to describe the classes and methods used in the application. The permanent generation is populated by the JVM at runtime based on classes in use by the application. In addition, Java SE library classes and methods may be stored here.

Classes may get collected (unloaded) if the JVM finds they are no longer needed and space may be needed for other classes. The permanent generation is included in a full garbage collection.

For more explaintion refer this link [Garbage Collector](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html)

Comment: I want to both upvote and downvote this.  It's well written and very clear, and there's a lot of really good information here.  But to be honest, it just doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Unreferenced objects are deleted when the Garbage Collection is triggered and that memory becomes available for use.

Answer (score 0):

The memory reclaimed and use it furthur

> An unused object, or unreferenced object, is no longer referenced by any part of your program. So the memory used by an unreferenced object can be reclaimed.

[`A pictorial here by oracle`](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

> Does it deletes all the data occupied by particular object? or just
>   marks the memory area used by the object as "reusable" so whenever new
>   objects are created they will be overwritten on this memory area?

I am not totally sure about this, but my guess would be just to ***mark*** the memory block as the ***free block*** and add it in the ***free pool for reuse***. Why pay so much by cleaning the data, when it is anyway going to be overwritten by other object.

Cleaning and again writing will take twice the time.